# Firebase return different values each time query

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase to check user is typing or not.

But each time I query the values from Firebase. The kind of values are different. I mean, sometimes the values are an array, a dictionary, an array with null value .... So when I tried to parse that value, my app is crashed.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)listenUserTypingGate {

    __weak typeof(self)this = self;

    [[_userTypingRef queryOrderedByKey] observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {
        if (this && snapshot.exists) {
            NSDictionary* typingData = snapshot.value;
            NSLog(@"ref: %@", _userTypingRef);
            NSLog(@"ref query: %@", [_userTypingRef queryOrderedByKey]);
            NSLog(@"data: %@", typingData);
        }
    }];
}
```

Result:

- I go to conversation 1. It is an array

> ref: https://testfir-199902.firebaseio.com/test-test/user_typing/0_1
>
> ref query: (/test-test/user_typing/0_1 {
>           i = ".key";
>       })
>
> data: (
>               {
>               avatar = "";
>               "user_typing" = 0;
>               username = Oanh;
>           },
>               {
>               avatar = "";
>               "user_typing" = 0;
>               username = "B\U00e9o";
>           }
>       )

- conversation 2: It is an array + null value

> ref: https://testfir-199902.firebaseio.com/test-test/user_typing/2_3
>
> ref query: (/test-test/user_typing/2_3 {
>           i = ".key";
>       })
>
> data: (
>           "",
>           "",
>               {
>               avatar = "";
>               "user_typing" = 0;
>               username = "H\U1ea1nh";
>           },
>               {
>               avatar = "";
>               "user_typing" = 0;
>               username = "L\U00f9n";
>           }
>       )

- conversation 3: it is a dictionary

> ref: https://testfir-199902.firebaseio.com/test-test/user_typing/4_5
>
> ref query: (/test-test/user_typing/4_5 {
>       i = ".key"; })
>
> data: {
>       4 =     {
>           avatar = "";
>           "user_typing" = 0;
>           username = "Ti\U1ebfn";
>       };
>       5 =     {
>           avatar = "";
>           "user_typing" = 0;
>           username = "L\U00ea";
>       }; }

Here is my struct on Firebase:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't take snapshot.value. Because your your last node has a child not a value.

So you have to retrieve first each child as a snapshot and then retrieve a value from particular child..

Here last Root node is actually 0 and 1 not 0_1.

```
    NSArray*childs = snap.children;
    for(int i = 0, i < childs.count  , i++ )
    {
            FIRDataSnapshot*snap = childs[i]
            NSDictionary* typingData = snap.value;
            NSLog(@"ref: %@", _userTypingRef);
            NSLog(@"ref query: %@", [_userTypingRef queryOrderedByKey]);
            NSLog(@"data: %@", typingData);

}
```

Comment: Ah. I understand. Thanks for your help.